# Graphics driver for Linux Mint 16 on Acer Aspire 5100 laptop

Tags: linux-mint, drivers

I have a 6-7 year old Acer Aspire 5100 laptop on which I installed Linux Mint 16 recently.

Everything works fine except that the screen flickers badly whenever the computer resumes from sleep (e.g., close the lid and open it back up). It seems to be a graphics driver problem.

However I couldn't find the specific graphics driver for this model. The sticker on the computer says "Graphics by ATI RADEON XPRESS 1100". The following is the output from `more /etc/*-release`

```
/etc/lsb-release
::::::::::::::
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16
DISTRIB_CODENAME=petra
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 16 Petra"
::::::::::::::
/etc/os-release
::::::::::::::
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="13.10, Saucy Salamander"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 13.10"
VERSION_ID="13.10"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

This is the output using `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS480/RS482/RS485 Host Bridge (rev 10)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Bridge [int gfx]
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Express Port 1
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Express Port 2
00:12.0 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 Serial ATA Controller (rev 80)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB Host Controller (rev 80)
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB Host Controller (rev 80)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB2 Host Controller (rev 80)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 SMBus Controller (rev 83)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 IDE Controller (rev 80)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 PCI-ISA Bridge (rev 80)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 PCI-PCI Bridge (rev 80)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS482M [Mobility Radeon Xpress 200]
06:01.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
06:02.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR2413/AR2414 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5005G(S) 802.11bg] (rev 01)
06:04.0 CardBus bridge: ENE Technology Inc CB-712/4 Cardbus Controller (rev 10)
06:04.1 FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc ENE PCI Memory Stick Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
06:04.2 SD Host controller: ENE Technology Inc ENE PCI Secure Digital Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
06:04.3 FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc: (rev 01)
06:04.4 FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When attempting to identify hardware I usually turn to these tools, since `lspci` can often be too vague.

#### lshw

This tool will show you extremely specific things, and a lot of it, so you'll want to kind of drill down into it. I usually start by getting the short list.

#### Example

```
$ sudo lshw -short
H/W path               Device      Class       Description
==========================================================
                                   system      To Be Filled By O.E.M. (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
/0                                 bus         M3A785GMH/128M
/0/0                               memory      64KiB BIOS
/0/4                               processor   AMD Athlon(tm) II X3 435 Processor
...
...
/0/100                             bridge      RS880 Host Bridge
/0/100/1                           bridge      ASRock Incorporation
/0/100/1/5                         display     RS880 [Radeon HD 4200]
/0/100/a                           bridge      RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 5)
/0/100/a/0             eth0        network     RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
/0/100/11              scsi0       storage     SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
/0/100/11/0.0.0        /dev/cdrom  disk        DVD+-RW TS-H653A
...
...

/0/105                             bridge      Family 10h Processor Link Control
/0/a                   scsi6       storage     
/0/a/0.0.0             /dev/sdb    disk        4095MB iPod
/0/a/0.0.0/0           /dev/sdb    disk        4095MB 
/0/a/0.0.0/0/1         /dev/sdb1   volume      78MiB Empty partition
/0/a/0.0.0/0/2         /dev/sdb2   volume      3820MiB Windows FAT volume
```

From the above output you'll notice that there are classes of devices. So you'll want to focus on the `display` class.

```
$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RS880 [Radeon HD 4200]
       vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:feaf0000-feafffff memory:fe900000-fe9fffff
```

#### hwinfo

The other tool I've used is `hwinfo`. This tool works similarly, where you can provide it which class of device you want to see information on. I'd use `--display`, if you want to see the other choices, check out the `hwinfo` man page.

#### Example

```
$ sudo hwinfo --display
29: PCI 105.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)             
  [Created at pci.318]
  UDI: /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/pci_1002_9710
  Unique ID: ul7N.uMd6rnoWsoE
  Parent ID: vSkL.WGcbfeFAG_0
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:05.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:01:05.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "ATI VGA compatible controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
  Device: pci 0x9710 
  SubVendor: pci 0x1849 "ASRock Incorporation"
  SubDevice: pci 0x9710 
  Driver: "fglrx_pci"
  Driver Modules: "fglrx"
  Memory Range: 0xd0000000-0xdfffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0xd000-0xdfff (rw)
  Memory Range: 0xfeaf0000-0xfeafffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xfe900000-0xfe9fffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 18 (37013695 events)
  I/O Ports: 0x3c0-0x3df (rw)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00001002d00009710sv00001849sd00009710bc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: radeon is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe radeon"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: fglrx is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe fglrx"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #9 (PCI bridge)

Primary display adapter: #29
```

#### Determining what card you have

The above output is pretty dense, so you can whittle it down a bit use a choice `grep` command as a filter.

#### lshw

```
$ sudo lshw -C video | grep product:
       product: RS880 [Radeon HD 4200]
```

The same can be done for the output from `hwinfo`.